# Cluster.stats with huge raster data possible

Tags: r, statistics, cluster-analysis, raster

As I have read in another thread  (http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/cluster-stats-td860343.html) large raster / cluster data in R cannot be processed via `cluster.stats`. (it states that 200.000 observations are already too much)

I have a raster of about 750.000 observations. Do you have any experience with examining such huge amount of data? A `subset` would be apropriate?
Thanks for sharing your experience!

Comment: Does it work with a sample? Always start with a manageable subset, to understand what you are doing. It may well be possible to cluster a sample only, then abstract to the full data set with near zero loss.

Comment: do you consider alternatives, like [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)?

Comment: Hi, better use CLARA in the cluster package. All other functions, to my knowledge, suffer from high memory requirements